# Euler Lagrange equations in a two-dimensional setting

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, inverse-problems

I am struggling to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations for the problem below. I have only recently been introduced to Euler-Lagrange equations and am struggling to understand them. I will also give the solution below to the problem, so if anyone has a derivation, that would be great.
\begin{equation*}
    J(u) = \int\int(E(x,y) - R(p,q))^{2} + \lambda \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}\right)^{2}
 \end{equation*}
where $p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $ q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

The Euler Lagrange equations for the problem yield
\begin{equation*}
    (E - R)R_{p} + \lambda ( p_{yy} - q_{xy}) = 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    (E - R)R_{q} + \lambda ( q_{xx} - p_{xy}) = 0
\end{equation*}

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $u$ is the argument of your functional but it is not present in the integral. Typo?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): The factor $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=0$ seems to vanish identically.